# Как переопределить стили редактора в дочерней теме

Tags: wordpress

Сделал дочернюю тему на основе twentytwentyone, создал файл стилей editor-styles.css, подключаю его так:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'my_theme_add_editor_styles');
function my_theme_add_editor_styles() {
    add_editor_style("editor-styles.css");
}
```

вижу в инспекторе что файл подключен, но для редактора все равно используются стили родительской темы.
Помогите разобраться

Comment: Если ты собрался править стили из админ панели сайта (что крайне нежелательно), то тебе необходимо зайти в настройки своей новой темы, предварительно выбрав её, а там выбрать Внешний вид-> Редактор темы. Там выбрать свой файл editor-styles.css и вносить правки туда. Но это плохая практика и таким заниматься, только в экстренных случаях

Comment: editor-styles.css в родителе точно нет? И точно есть и доступен у дочки?

Comment: editor-styles.css в родителе есть мне как раз нужно его переопределить, у дочки файл доступен я вижу его подключение в head в браузере

Comment: Ну так почитай описание функции: "Если используется дочерняя тема, то проверяются оба каталога: дочерний и родительский, и в случае наличия двух файлов, ***оба будут подключены.**" А файлы переопределять не нужно - в своём файле нужно задать свои стили.

Comment: Я имел ввиду переопределить стили, я вообще не вижу что стили из моего файла применялись к редактору, а в настройках редактора вот это написано:
Отключено: Файл таблицы стилей с именем editor-style.css не был добавлен вашей темой.

Comment: Добавлю что надпись:
 Отключено: Файл таблицы стилей с именем editor-style.css не был добавлен вашей темой.
исчезла только после того как я деактивировал и активировал тему заново, но стили так и не применились

Comment: В общем спасибо всем кто написал, стили я подключил просто переименовав название файла editor-styleы.css в my-editor-style.css и все заработало, больше ничего не менял и это странно , если кто объяснит почему так будет хорошо.
Всем спасибо.